# Eclipse: showing git changes

Tags: eclipse, git

I had a nice feature in eclipse when I first installed it. Once a file is added to git and changes are committed, any new changes to that file would show in gray color in eclipse. I could hover over on the left of the changed line and eclipse would show me the changes I have made there. I find it very useful and use it quite often. More importantly I can see all the changes at a glance in a file. Suddenly this feature is gone from the eclipse after doing some random settings change. Now I can't turn on the feature again. If anyone has any idea how to get the feature back would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Right-click** the **left ruler** and enable ***Show Quick Diff* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)**.

This shows changes as you described **by default since the last save**. To show changes **since the last Git commit** instead, change the preferences in ***General > Editors > Text Editors > Quick Diff***.

For **Git blame right-click the left ruler** and choose ***Show Revision Information*** which cannot be enabled by default.