# Eclipse git line diff status

Tags: eclipse, git, diff, gedit

I'm using Gedit as my general purpose editor. However for some bigger projects Eclipse is becoming better choice.

The only feature I miss from Gedit is git line diff status:

[image: gedit git line diff status plugin]

Green is new line, orange modified, red removed. It it possible to have something  similar in Eclipse?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52016175

Comment: It is also necessary to switch  General > Editors > Text Editors > Quick Diff to Latest Git revision

Comment: That's cool. I didn't know that yet. Thanks for pointing that out. Please answer your question yourself.